# German character ü converted to question mark in the REST response

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, jax-ws

I am very new to REST web services.I am seeing issue while getting the german character ü in REST service response.

When the data is returned from the web service method it correctly has the character but when it reaches the caller its converted to junk.

Any inputs would help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is the issue of mis-treating unicode data with some other encoding.Make sure to include `charset=utf-8` in Content-type headers of your response. Say response content type is json, then content type header should be `Content-type:"application/json"; charset=utf-8`. Moreover clients need to render response data with correct encoding.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Everywhere its correctly encoded with UTF-8 as formatting.
Actually it works in some cases. In the cases where it works ,I see the object(POJO) to be returned is converted to string by writeValueAsString of ObjectWriter(Jackson  class)and then wrapped in ResponseEntity<String> (provided by Spring) before returning .

In the cases where it does not work , I see response is returned as plain string. would this make any difference?

Comment: Are you sending content type headers in response, identifying response as unicode data

Comment: Also see if you can use unicode string object instead of plain string, if there is such a distinction in java

Comment: I see that when I wrap the response in ResponseEntity<String> (provided by Spring)  and add headers by passing it to the constructors of ResponseEntity ,it works.Not sure what's the difference.difference. Editing the original question.